# Declaring an array with predefined elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to declare an array that has a number of elements that are already defined (the point of this is for easy code maintenance). I'm unsure what my issue is, but this is what I have so far:

```
var coefficients = new array(   'AgeAtDiagnosis'                : 0.0068313 ,
                                    'TransformedMelaNomaThickness'  : 1.829936 ,
                                    'MelanomaThickness'             : 0.0377696 ,
                                    'Ulceration'                    : 0.3779279 ,
                                    'Metastasis'                    : 1.063668 ,
                                    'LymphNodes'                    : 0.7789897);
```

To help better explain, this is the PHP version of what I'm trying to acomplish:

```
var coefficients = new array(   'AgeAtDiagnosis'                => 0.0068313 ,
                                    'TransformedMelaNomaThickness'  => 1.829936 ,
                                    'MelanomaThickness'             => 0.0377696 ,
                                    'Ulceration'                    => 0.3779279 ,
                                    'Metastasis'                    => 1.063668 ,
                                    'LymphNodes'                    => 0.7789897);
```

How do I approach this problem in javascript?

Comment: Does… does that work in PHP?

Comment: What's the purpose of posting invalid syntax? With 1400K it calls for a downvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScript, it's not an "array"; it's an object literal that behaves like a dictionary.

```
var stuff = {
    key1: 1.2345,
    key2: 200,
    key3: 'foobar'
};
console.log(stuff.key1, stuff.key2, stuff.key3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use {} instead of new array:

```
var coefficients = { AgeAtDiagnosis : '0.0068313'}
```